# MongoDB DataSource Configuration In JBoss Server

Tags: java, mongodb, jboss, datasource, jndi

How to configure MongoDB DataSource JNDI in JBoss Server.
I downloaded MongoDB jar (**mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar**) and deployed using admin console, it got successfully deployed but when I went to add Datasource in customize option I am not able to see MongoDB driver, the only one option available was h2. Why so? Do I have to do any other configuration change or am I missing any step?

I Even tried to manually create the MongoDB driver and datasource but that is also not working.
I placed module.xml and mongo-java-driver- 3.4.2.jar to the following path 
..\devstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\modules\system\layers\base\org\mongodb\main

```
--------- module.xml ---------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.mongodb">
<resources>
<resource-root path="mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
<module name="javax.api"/>
<module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
</module>

--------------standalone.xml ------------

<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mongodb" pool-name="mongodb" 
enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
  <connection-url>jdbc:mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/example;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
   <driver>mongodb</driver>
 </datasource>
<driver name="mongodb" module="org.mongodb">
   <xa-datasource-class>mongodb.jdbc.MongoXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
 </driver>
```

I was getting the following error when i started the server

```
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("data-source" => "mongodb")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable 
dependencies" => [
"org.wildfly.data-source.mongodb is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mongodb]",
"jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/mongodb is missing 
[jboss.jdbc-driver.mongodb]"
]}
23:51:44,277 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] 
(Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("data-source" => "mongodb")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable 
dependencies" => [
"org.wildfly.data-source.mongodb is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mongodb]",
"jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/mongodb is missing 
[jboss.jdbc-driver.mongodb]",
"org.wildfly.data-source.mongodb is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mongodb]"
]}
```

Could you let me know how to do JNDI Datasource configuration in JBoss Server ?? Please explain in detail as I am new for JNDI Configuration

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://www.progress.com/blogs/configure-connect-for-jdbc-mongodb-driver-with-jboss-eap-64[enter link description here](https://www.progress.com/blogs/configure-connect-for-jdbc-mongodb-driver-with-jboss-eap-64)